# Trying to make sense of a basic WordCount MapReduce example

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

Started using Hadoop recently and struggling to make sense of a few things. Here is a basic WordCount example that I'm looking at (count the number of times each word appears):

```
Map(String docid, String text):
 for each word term in text:
 Emit(term, 1);

Reduce(String term, Iterator<Int> values):
 int sum = 0;
 for each v in values:
 sum += v;
 Emit(term, sum);
```

Firstly, what is `Emit(w,1)` supposed to be doing? I notice that in all of the examples I look at the second parameter is always set to *1*, but I can't seem to find an explanation on it.

Also, just to clarify - am I correct in saying that *term* is the key and *sum* in Reduce form the key-value pairs (respectively)? If this is the case, is *values* simply a list of 1's for each *term* that got emitted from Map? That's the only way I can make sense of it, but these are just assumptions.

Apologies for the noob question, I have looked at tutorials but a lot of the time I find that a lot of confusing terminology is used and overall basic things are made to be more complicated than they actually are so I'm struggling a little to make sense of this.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Take this input as an example word count input.

Mapper will split this sentence into words.

```
Take,1
this,1
input,1
as,1
an,1
example,1
word,1
count,1
input,1
```

Then, the reducer receives "groups" of the same word (or **key**) and lists of the grouped values like so (and additionally sorts the keys, but that's not important for this example)

```
Take, (1)
this, (1)
input (1, 1)
etc...
```

As you can see, the key `input` has been "reduced" into a single element, that you can loop over and sum the values and emit like so

```
Take,1
this,1
input,2 
etc...
```

Answer (score 2):

Good question.

As explained, the mapper outputs a sequence of `(key, value)` pairs, in this case of the form `(word, 1)` for each word, which the reducer receives grouped as `(key, <1,1,...,1>)`, sums up the terms in the list and returns `(key, sum)`. Note that it is *not* the reducer who does the grouping; it's the map-reduce environment.

The [map-reduce programming model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) is different from the one we're used to working in, and it's often not obvious how to implement an algorithm in this model. (Think, for example, about how would you implement a k-means clustering.)

I recommend Chapter 2 of the freely-available [Mining of Massive Data Sets](http://www.mmds.org/) [book](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/book.pdf) by Leskovec et al. See also [the corresponding slides](http://www.mmds.org/mmds/v2.1/ch02-mapreduce.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and also the resources - I'll give those books / slide a look.